# How to Find All Employees under Each Company in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a sql query where 2 or more people worked at the same company. So I need to find groups of people who worked for the same company. I have 100 companies, and a few thousand people, so I would just get a grouping of people who worked for the same company, namely, have an overlapping work history in any point in time.
I have employees ssn, company ein.  So if person a worked at CVS and person b worked at cvs during a given time, then the query would show that person a and person b worked at CVS.

Comment: Can you provide some more info? Add the tag to specify the dialect, add the tables you are using and if you can even an example of the output you want to get

Comment: So columns are employee id and business ein. For example, the output would show employee 123 worked with at least one other employee at 2 distinct business.